# Calculate orbit height from tangential velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, satellites

Is it possible to calculate the altitude of a satellite orbiting a planet, just from the planet's mass and the satellite's velocity, assuming that the satellite is in a perfect circular orbit? If so, what would the equation be? I've derived the following equation: $G\frac{M}{v^2} = r$ , however I don't think it's correct.

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail. Why don't you think the equation you ended up with is correct? Have you done the obvious Google searches e.g. for *orbital speed*?

Comment: Yes, equation $G\frac{M}{v^2}=r$ is correct. For more info about orbital speed(and how equation looks like in elliptic orbit) See this page: [Orbital Speed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_speed)

Comment: Remember that this gives you the distance from the satellite to the center of the planet. If you want the altitude above the planet surface you need to subtract it by the radius of the planet.

Comment: Thanks for that - that's probably why the values I was getting from my equation appeared incorrect...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do that with Newtonian mechanics (specifically [Newton's second law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion#Newton.27s_second_law)) and the [universal gravitational force law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation) (also by Newton). Some knowledge of circular orbits is also necessary, such as the required acceleration.